# Getting javascript to handle flash (firefox problems)

Tags: javascript, flash

I am having some issues passing commands through to flash from javascript. My code finally works in both IE and Chrome. Sadly it doesnt do anything i firefox. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //function setCurrentPage(newPage) {
    //    currentPage = newPage;
    //    SendDataToFlashMovie(newPage);
    //}
    function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    if (window.document[movieName]){

        return window.document[movieName];

    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1){
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
            return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    else{

            return document.getElementById(movieName);

    }
    }
    function SendDataToFlashMovie(newPage){
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("java");
    flashMovie.callAs(newPage);
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onClick="SendDataToFlashMovie('Home')">Home</a>
```

FLASH

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="java" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="java.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="devicefont" value="false" />
<param name="salign" value="" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />

<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object id="java" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="java.swf" width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="java.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="devicefont" value="false" />
<param name="salign" value="" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<EMBED src="java.swf" quality="high" swliveconnect="true" width="550" height="400" name="java" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</EMBED>
<!--<![endif]-->
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
</a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your flash file (there is a handy [code generator](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html) - use 'Dynamic publishing').

Then the JS code will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendDataToFlashMovie(newPage){
        var flashMovie = document.getElementById("java");
        flashMovie.callAs(newPage);
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="SendDataToFlashMovie('Home')">Home</a>
```

Comment: You should approve this answer as SWFObject is the right way to do!

Comment: @Florent Actually, for me it didn't work when I was doing a project with javascript-to-actionscript calls, and used SWFObject. So it's not always the best way to go.

Comment: I successfully use SWFObject with `ExernalInterface` within a lot of project. So yes, you did it wrong.

Comment: Perfect. Works in all browsers :D Thank you so much!!